# Five items per row with flex, aligned left

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 32 list items separated into two lists that need to be displayed as 5 per row. I can't edit HTML and since there are 52 items, one is always left on its own. And it takes the entire width of a row, when I want it to be left aligned and 20% as the rest. How can I fix this?

To make things easier to understand, here's my code. If there's a better way to do this, please let me know. Thanks!

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 20%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li class="item">Content</li>
  <li class="item">Content</li>
  <li class="item">Content</li>
  <li class="item">Content</li>
  <li class="item">Content</li>
  <li class="item">Content</li>
</ul>
<ul class="container">
  <li class="item">Content</li>
  <li class="item">Content</li>
  <li class="item">Content</li>
  <li class="item">Content</li>
  <li class="item">Content</li>
  <li class="item">Content</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `flex-grow` value `1` in `flex: 1 20%` will make them fill the remaining space when there is one, so change it to `flex-basis: 20%` and it will keep same width on all flex items.

Also remove the `justify-content: space-between` or else it will create an equal space between any item more than 1 but less than 5 preventing them to align left.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;  
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.item {
  flex-basis: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li class="item">Content</li>
  <li class="item">Content</li>
  <li class="item">Content</li>
  <li class="item">Content</li>
  <li class="item">Content</li>
  <li class="item">Content</li>
</ul>
<ul class="container">
  <li class="item">Content</li>
  <li class="item">Content</li>
  <li class="item">Content</li>
  <li class="item">Content</li>
  <li class="item">Content</li>
  <li class="item">Content</li>
</ul>
```